# Data annoation Valdiation with jquery validation in client side in mvc

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have used Datannoation validation in model like this

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z][\w.]+|[0-9][0-9_.]*[a-zA-Z]+[\w.]*)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid username")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "User name is required")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [Display(Name = "User Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
```

In View

```
   <p>
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new {@id="UserNamereg", @Class = "span5", @placeholder  = "UserName",onchange = "CheckRegUserAvailibility(this,'/Account/CheckUserName');"})
    </p>
```

Also I want to check if the username already exits in database for this I am using jquery.

```
function CheckAvailibility(thisElm, targeturl, avilibilityfieldname) {
    var stridvalue = $(thisElm).val();
    var strid = $(thisElm).attr("id");
    var data = $("#" + strid).serialize();
    var errorMsg = "The " + avilibilityfieldname.toLowerCase() + " '" + stridvalue + "' is not available. Try another " + avilibilityfieldname.toLowerCase() + "."
    if (stridvalue != "") {
        $.post(targeturl, data, function (responseResult) {
            if (responseResult == "false") {

                $("#" + strid).removeClass("input-validation-valid").addClass("input-validation-error");
                $("#" + strid).siblings("span").removeClass("field-validation-valid").addClass("field-validation-error");
                $("#" + strid).siblings("span").empty().html(errorMsg);

                $("#" + strid).val("");
            } else if (responseResult == "true") {

                $("#" + strid).removeClass("input-validation-error").addClass("input-validation-valid");
                $("#" + strid).siblings("span").removeClass("field-validation-error").addClass("field-validation-valid");
            }

        });

    }
}
```

The problem is that only jquery validation works in client side as i am using "onchnge" event.Is there any way to make both validation work correctly?Thankx for help

Comment: have you looked at the remotevalidation attribute?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came up with editing some lines of code.
I removed this line of code in jquery.

```
  $("#" + strid).siblings("span").removeClass("field-validation-error").addClass("field-validation-valid");
```

After this both jquery validation and Datannoation validation in model workd complety.